# How to access unserialise Laravel Queue data?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-queue

I need to get the value of projectId from the queue payload. When I try with the following

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
      $payload = json_decode( $event->job->getRawBody() );
      $data = unserialize( $payload->data->command );
      \Log::info((array) $data );
  });
```

I get the following output:

```
[2019-12-12 11:34:35] local.INFO: array (
 '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'projectId' => '1',
 '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'job' => NULL,
'connection' => NULL,
'queue' => NULL,
'chainConnection' => NULL,
'chainQueue' => NULL,
'delay' => NULL,
'chained' => 
array (
    ),
 )
```

How can I get the value of "projectId?

Comment: Can you post a raw body example of the queue job?

Comment: I have fixed it. Posted the fix below.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with the following code:

```
     Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event){

        $payload = $event->job->payload();
        $job =  unserialize($payload['data']['command']);
        $projectId = $job->projectId;
   });
```